# DISTINCT COUNT returning SQL error

Tags: mysql

Why is the following SQL query returning an error?

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT rm.id) 
FROM ts_room rm
   LEFT JOIN ts_roomfacilities rf
      ON rm.id = rf.room_id
   LEFT JOIN ts_facilities f
      ON f.id = rf.facilities_id
   LEFT JOIN ts_building b
      ON rm.building_id=b.id;
```

It seems logical at first glance!

Here is my SQLFiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a59fc/20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put a space between `COUNT` and the first parenthesis. See it works now:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a59fc/24

By the way, the error message you received at first tells you EXACTLY where your syntax error is.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a space between `COUNT` and the parentheses because it is a function.  Write it as `COUNT(`.